# Display where are thrown an error 500 with NodeJS and Express

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

I'm using node and I try to redirect the display for 404 and 500 error.

For now I have this code who work fine :

```
/* ... Some require here ... */

var app = module.exports = express();

/* ... Some app config here */

// Setup my routes
routes.setup(app);

// Handling 404 errors
app.use(function(req, res) {
   res.end("Oups !", 404);
});

// Handling 500 errors
app.use(function(error, req, res, next) {
   console.log("Display error : ", error);
   res.end("Oups !", 500);
});

// Start server
var server = app.listen(config.PORT);
```

Now if on my code I do `throw new Error("An error here");` On the console.log I just got a string :

```
Display error : An error here
```

And if I remove the part for handling error 500, on the console log I automatically got a description of where the error come from :

```
Error: An error here
    at Layer.handle (/.../app.js:94:7)
    at trim_prefix (/.../node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:226:17)
    at c (/.../node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:198:9)
    at Function.proto.process_params (/.../node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:251:12)
    at next (/.../node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:189:19)
    at next (/.../node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:166:38)
    at next (/.../node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:166:38)
    at next (/.../node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:166:38)
    at next (/.../node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:166:38)
    at Layer.handle (/.../app.js:50:5)
```

How can I get the information about where the throw is fired ?

Thank all !

Answer (score 0):

```
/ Setup my routes
routes.setup(app);
```

may be you have the problem in routes.setup(app);

first remove the line code test your application

Comment: No, my rooter is fine. I can remove it, and i got the same result

Answer (score 0):

Yes ! After reading half the web documentation I found the solution !

The `error` var return on the function isn't a String as displayed on `console.log()`. But an object..

And event if `Object.keys(error)` return an empty array, some attribute exist and the path information is defined on `error.stack.

For more information : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Error